# Let eclipse / app 'forget' the previous layout?

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

Simple question: How do I let eclipse/my app forget the previous layout?

More specific: I would like my android app not to go back to the original or 'home' layout when pressing back after it went in fullscreen mode. Instead, it should close the app or just do nothing.

I hope the answer is simple too, there must be some code to block this?

thanks

Comment: You mean you want to write a custom home activity? Or you want to override the home button? By the way it is simple to override the back button.

Comment: I want the app just to block the 'back' button, but it still has to come up with a menu and the home button should work too. So i would like the app not to go back to the previous layout.How do i override it then? I dont want it to override the menu button for example, and i dont see any code for the back button in the main.java class

Comment: To override the back button is simple by overriding the of onkeydown function. It is not possible to override the home button. But you can write a custom Home activity you with a special intent filter.

Comment: How do I override it then? Because i cannot see any code for the back button. I am kinda new in this so I dont see how i can override the back button.

Comment: I'm in a train with my mobile so I cannot write the code now, but the function has a parameter keycode which has the value KeyEvent.BackKey or so, then you just need to return false

Comment: I typed "[android] override back button" into the search bar at the top of this page.  It worked!

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, but Maver1ck already fixed it.            Hell, if I couldnt ask some questions here I would have already stopped! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

  //do whatever you want here

}}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this was the right code. You only missed 'return false' i think, or it wont work. You guys are great!